# Signing apk with same package name and key

Tags: java, android, mobile, apk

Suppose I write an app for android in the Play Store and then I create a new version in a new project in a separate workspace. If I use the same application name, package name, and keystore and key, can I replace the existing app in the Play Store? Or would it consider the second app different? I use Eclipse if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new version from any other eclipse. It will consider it same app. The things that matter are:

- Keystore
- Bundle Identifier

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use different package name and app name.if you upload you app new version.you have to change your App version in Androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the same package name, keystore and key, it shouldn't be a problem. Play store only verifies the package name to be the same. You can use Eclipse/Android Studio, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,With same appication name, package name, and keystore and key,Play Store will replace the existing app.